# How loss in RNN/LSTM is calculated?

Tags: neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm learing how LSTM works by practicing with time series training data(input is a list of features and output is a scalar). 
There is a problem that i couldnt understand when calculating loss for RNN/LSTM:

How loss is calculated? Is it calculated at each time i give the nn new input or acummulated through all the given inputs and then be backprop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer does not depend on the neural network model.
It depends on your choice of optimization method.

If you are using batch gradient descent, the loss is averaged over the whole training set. This is often impractical for neural networks, because the training set is too big to fit into RAM, and each optimization step takes a lot of time.

In stochastic gradient descent, the loss is calculated for each new input. The problem with this method is that it is noisy.

In mini-batch gradient descent, the loss is averaged over each new minibatch - a subsample of inputs of some small fixed size. Some [variation](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/) of this method is typically used in practice.

So, the answer to your question depends on the minibatch size you choose.

[image: Convergence of gradient descent depending on minibatch size]

(Image is from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/gradient-descent-algorithm-and-its-variants-10f652806a3))

Comment: it seems like i've over-thought the problem. Btw, thanks a lot for helping me

Answer (score 3):

@seed Answer is correct. However, in LSTM, or any RNN architecture, the loss for each instance, across all time steps, is added up. In other words, you'll have (L0@t0, L1@t1, ... LT@tT) for each sample in your input batch. Add those losses separately for each instance in the batch. Finally average the losses of each input instance to get the average loss for a current batch

For more information please visit: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/teaching/cs-230/cheatsheet-recurrent-neural-networks